# HTML content encoded, started with '&#' sign

Tags: email, encoding, big5

I have received an email and the body is formed in HTML format. However, I was wondering how can I decode the encoded content as following:

`<a href=3Dhttp://&#65296;&#65294;&#65351;&#65351;&#47;&#68;&#70;&#116;&#50;&#85;>`

Could anyone tell me how to decode the string? The transfer encoding is Qouted-printable, and the charset is big5. However, I tried to decode the content with qp-decoder and nothing works. Thanks.

Comment: I tried http://www.base64decode.org/ and I see some chinese letters.

Answer (score 0):

Try the link below:
http://toolswebtop.com/text/process/decode/BIG-5

I tried your link and got 3Dhttp://０．ｇｇ/DFt2U